# Pre-trained "CNN" model for "Head Pose" detection

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Dears,

If you please, I am trying to implement a "Head Pose" (Front, Up, Down, Left, Right) detection project using "CNN" and I need to use a pre-trained network as I have small amount of training images.

My questions are:

- What is the best architecture for such a task (LeNet, VGG, ...)?
- How to decide which layer/layers to train with my data?

Note: I am using "Python/Tensorflow/Keras" and I have a mid-range Nvidia GPU.

Thank you very much.